# PHP set_error_handler() always returns null

Tags: php, error-handling

I can't work out what's going wrong.

The following always results in outputting "Could not set an error handler":

```
<?php

function die_on_error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
    echo "\n\nThere was an error. Today is a good day to die.";
    echo "\n\n\$errno: $errno";
    echo "\n\n\$errstr: $errstr";
    echo "\n\n\$errfile: $errfile";
    echo "\n\n\$errline: $errline";
    echo "\n\n\$errcontext: ";
    var_dump($errcontext);
    die();
}

if (is_null(set_error_handler('die_on_error'))){
    die("\n\nCould not set an error handler.");
}
```

Comment: Are you actually generating an error?

Comment: try with `ob_start('die_on_error');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to have an error to execute this function,If errors occur before the script is executed   the custom error handler cannot be called since it is not registered at that time.

```
function die_on_error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
    echo"This is sparta";
    echo "\n\n\$errno: $errno";
    echo "\n\n\$errstr: $errstr";
    echo "\n\n\$errfile: $errfile";
    echo "\n\n\$errline: $errline";
    echo "\n\n\$errcontext: ";
    var_dump($errcontext);
    die();
}

 print_r(set_error_handler('die_on_error'));

trigger_error("Incorrect  array", E_USER_WARNING);
```

[**demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2cvm0k)

Comment: Great, it works. But I don't get it! Firstly, in both your code, `die_on_error` is defined before the call to `set_error_handler`. Secondly, in both cases, no error occurs before `set_error_handler`. *confused*

Comment: Aaah I was being really stupid. `set_error_handler` returns null even if you have successfully set a custom error handler, if the previous error handler was the PHP default. The only time it wouldn't return null is if you replace a custom error handler with something else

Comment: exactly ... you got it before my comment, nice R&D  :D

Answer (score 0):

I have a complicated singleton class for handling errors, but I also like to know that all has worked ok.

My solution was to silence error reporting and trigger an error with a specific string to check for then set a variable within the class to true and check against that.

something like

```
class myerror
{
    private $enabled;

    public function __construct()
    {
       if ($this->set_handler() === false) die('Error Handler Failed To Init...');
    }

    private function set_handler()
    {
        $methodVariable = array('myerror', 'error_handler');
        if (is_callable($methodVariable, true, $callable_name) === false return false;
        @set_error_handler($callable_name, E_ALL);
        trigger_error('Error Init', E_USER_NOTICE);
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    public static function error_handler($errNo, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine)
    {
        if($errStr == 'Error Init')
        {
            $this->enabled = true;
            return;
        }
        // do something with the error
    }
}
```

This is just a non tested example but I hope it gives you some idea how I solved the problem.
:)